# Create and initialize dictionary from list

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a way to combine below two statements into one, so you can create and initialize a dictionary from an array in one single statement?

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
myList.ForEach(i => myDictionary.Add(i.property1, i.property2));
```

(whether or not that makes the code easier to read is another topic :-))

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `Enumerable` class has a nice class extension for the `IEnumerable<>`: Try

```
var myDictionary = myList.ToDictionary(key => key.property1, value => value.property2);
```